# Distributed training using multiple GPUs with tensorflow.slim.learning

Tags: tensorflow, tf-slim

I understand that TensorFlow supports distributed training.

I find `num_clones` in `train_image_classifier.py` so that I can use multiple GPUs locally.

```
python $TF_MODEL_HOME/slim/train_image_classifier.py \
--num_clones=2
--train_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} \
--dataset_name=imagenet \
--dataset_split_name=train \
--dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} \
--model_name=vgg_19 \
--batch_size=32 \
--max_number_of_steps=100
```

How do I use multiple GPUs on different hosts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `--worker_replicas=<no of hosts>` to train on multiple hosts with same number of GPUs. Apart from that, you have to configure `--task`, `--num_ps_tasks`, `--sync_replicas`, `--replicas_to_aggregate` if you are training on multiple hosts.

I'd suggest you give [Horovod](https://github.com/uber/horovod) a try. I'm planning to give it a try in a couple of days.

Comment: If i have 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2, one gpu each host, then i run above cmd at 192.168.0.1, add `--worker_replicas="192.168.0.2"  --task=1 --num_ps_tasks=1 --sync_replicas=true`, right?

Comment: @SnShines
Assuming a scenario of 2 machines (server1 and server2) with 3 gpus on each, care to provide a concrete example of how many processes should be spawned and example values for the flags that you described?

Comment: Hi, any chance you could explain the difference between `worker_replicas`, `ps_tasks`, `num_ps_pasks`, `task`, `num_replicas`, `num_clones`?

Comment: @Austin, did you understand the difference between worker_replicas, ps_tasks, num_ps_pasks, task, num_replicas, num_clones?